# I need to sort an array of objects into a new object where the sort is based on the callbacks return

Tags: javascript, object, associative-array

the function I am supposed to implement is

> function groupBy(array, callback) { }

The function will sort the array based on the return value of the callback.

An example is:

> var list = [{id: "102", name: "Alice"},
>                 {id: "205", name: "Bob", title: "Dr."},
>                 {id: "592", name: "Clyde", age: 32}];
>
> groupBy(list, function(i) { return i.id; });
>
> Returns:
>
> {
>       "102": [{id: "102", name: "Alice"}],
>       "205": [{id: "205", name: "Bob", title: "Dr."}],
>       "592": [{id: "592", name: "Clyde", age: 32}]   }

Comment: JS objects don't maintain order. So your desired result is not guaranteed either. PS: there are no associative arrays in JS.

Comment: Would it be possible to store the callback's return value and store them as keys in the object we are returning?

Comment: Totally. Just create a new object and use that key and the value.

Comment: "The function will sort the array based on the return value of the callback" If the function is sorting, then why do you call it `groupBy`? And telling by your example, you want to group, not sort. Please don't mix these two terms like that, as they describe completely different tasks. And you seem to mean only one of them and not the other.

Comment: So you have to implement `groupBy`, OK. What's the question? And what's your problem? At the moment you only describe your task. Your neither ask a question nor do you describe a problem with that task.

Comment: @naikrima if my solution does not help you, let me know and we can figure it out together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map to maintain an ordered list

```js
var list = [{
  id: "102",
  name: "Alice"
}, {
  id: "205",
  name: "Bob",
  title: "Dr."
}, {
  id: "592",
  name: "Clyde",
  age: 32
}];

function callBack(list) {
  var ordered = new Map();
  for (let i of list) {
    ordered.set(i.id, [i])
  }
  return ordered;
}
console.log(...callBack(list));
```